# Comparing a scriptlet variable in c:if

Tags: jsp, jstl

Here's some code

```
<% String what = (String)session.getAttribute("BANG"); %>
<c:set var="bang" value="Song" />
```

I'm getting a string out of the session and I want to compare it to a string in a jstl variable.

I have tried an if in

```
<% if() { %> some text <% } %>
```

also tried

```
<c:if test="${va1 == va2}" </c:if>
```

Comment: I am not clear as to what you want to accomplish. Your first line at the top creates a scripting variable and assigns it a value from the session-scoped variable. Your  second line sets a value for the page-scoped variable. What condition are you trying to test in the third and fourth lines?

Comment: Please don't mix "scriptlets" with "javascript". Those are absolutely not the same. I fixed the (initially very confusing) question title.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, it's recommended to stop using *scriptlets*, those `<% %>` things. They don't work nicely together with JSTL/EL. You should choose for the one or the other. As *scriptlets* are [officially discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202) since a decade, it makes sense to stop using them.

---

Coming back to your concrete question, the following *scriptlet*

```
<% String what = (String)session.getAttribute("BANG"); %>
```

can just be done in EL as follows

```
${BANG}
```

So, this should do it for you:

```
<c:if test="${BANG == 'Song'}">
    This block will be executed when the session attribute with the name "BANG"
    has the value "Song".
</c:if>
```

Or, if you *really* need to have `"Song"` in a variable, then so:

```
<c:set var="bang" value="Song" />
<c:if test="${BANG == bang}">
    This block will be executed when the session attribute with the name "BANG"
    has the same value as the page attribute with the name "bang".
</c:if>
```

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)
- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)